# HttpContext.Response.Redirect(url, false); causes 504 error on Amazon AWS environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, sitecore, http-status-codes, page-lifecycle

I have next setup:

- Sitecore(ASP.Net based CMS) 7.2 x 2 content delivery servers hosted
  in Amazon AWS.
- Amazon web services(AWS) elastic load balancer(ELB) before Sitecore
  servers.
- Akamai caching before AWS.(should not effect I guess)

I have next 2 controller actions:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult MyAction1()
{
  return Redirect("some url");  
}
```

and

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult MyAction2()
{
  Response.Redirect("some url");
  return Redirect("some url");  
}
```

Both 2 actions works fine locally. But on AWS hosting first(`MyAction1`) doesn't work. It throws 504 error(Gateway timeout) from ELB(there is 1 minute timeout).
I decided to compare difference between `Response.Redirect("some url");` and `return Redirect("some url");`.
Here is decompiled code for `Redirect("some url")`:

```
    if (context == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
    }
    if (context.IsChildAction)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(MvcResources.RedirectAction_CannotRedirectInChildAction);
    }
    string url = UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl(this.Url, context.HttpContext);
    context.Controller.TempData.Keep();
    if (this.Permanent)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.RedirectPermanent(url, false);
        return;
    }
    context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(url, false);
```

I put this code in action and checked it line by line. Action starts to cause 504 error when `endResponse` parameter in `context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(url, false)` is `false`. In other words:

This code works:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult MyAction1()
{
  Response.Redirect("some url", true);
  return Redirect("some url");  
}
```

and this code cause 504 error

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult MyAction2()
{
  Response.Redirect("some url", false);
  return Redirect("some url");  
}
```

Depending on `endResponse` parameter value, `Response.End()` is called. If it is not called, I got 504 error. I wonder what can cause this behavior. I am going to investigate what could be executed after this action that can cause long running of `Request`. But as code works fine locally I have doubts whether AWS ELB could process 302 request by itself without transferring back to browser and it causes issue. What I also tried: run this code on AWS environment on RDP without ELB, and it works fine. So, there is high probability that issue is with AWS ELB.

Any suggestions, what could be wrong? Where should I look at?

Comment: Why would you set `end_response` to `false`?  You're done and ready to release the response, right?  It sounds like ELB throws 504 because the response never... ends... so it keeps waiting, and times out.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I don't set it to false. I used return *Redirect("some url");*, which is correct. I should not call *Response.Redirect*, I should return action result. When I looked on its implementation, it contains *Response.Redirect("some url", false);*.